# Could not open port /dev/ttyS0: Errno 13: Permission denied: '/dev/ttyS0'

Tags: serial, pi-3b+, communication

I am getting this error whenever I am trying to run this code:

```
import serial
from time import sleep

ser = serial.Serial ("/dev/ttyS0", 9600)    #Open port with baud rate
while True:
    received_data = ser.read()              #read serial port
    sleep(0.03)
    data_left = ser.inWaiting()             #check for remaining byte
    received_data += ser.read(data_left)
    print (received_data)                   #print received data
    ser.write(received_data)
```

Error:
  Could not open port /dev/ttyS0: Errno 13: Permission denied: '/dev/ttyS0'

I referred [This link](https://www.circuits.dk/setup-raspberry-pi-3-gpio-uart/) for configuring my RPI model 3B+
I also tried [This link](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=197823) for this problem but not successful. 
My user "pi" is already the member of the `dialout` group.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ groups pi
pi : pi adm tty dialout cdrom sudo audio video plugdev games users input netdev spi i2c gpio
```

Still, whenever I am trying to run this code, this error pops up. Would be thankful for any help and suggestion.

Comment: Please edit the result of `ls -l /dev/ttyS0` into your question.

Comment: Are you running Raspbian or some other OS? What does a ```udevadm info -a -n /dev/ttyS0``` command show?

Comment: @Dougie I am running latest Raspbian, and will be editing this comment once I get to my system.

Answer (score 1):

Your process is likely not running with elevated permissions. You should run it using **sudo**. Also, your programming model should be an event-driven one, not a poll in place one using a constant read and sleep -- that won't work well at all. You can attach an event handler to the ser object and only read when data is present.